# How to deploy REST with basic authentication in Solr 6.6.1

Tags: rest, authentication, curl, solr, lucene

I have deployed Apache Solr 6.6.1 with basic authentication by following their [reference guide](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/basic-authentication-plugin.html). At the end they have discussed how to use curl with security. For my case, I am using REST API to query SOLR. How can I request solr via REST API with basic authentication enabled ?

Comment: Which client are you using? The REST API is exposed through HTTP, so it's the same as for cURL. You can usually embed the username and password in the url directly: `http://user:pass@serverhost/solr`.

Comment: We have PHP client, second client is AJAX.